# CefSharp Wait For Element to Appear Javascript Not Triggering Raise Event

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I've been at this quite a while, have dug everywhere and I'm about at my wits end. The solution seems simple: Inject some javascript code into the chromium browser to wait for an element to appear (the browser has already finished loading and without waiting for the element, my .net code races past the automation parts I want to do on the page), then proceed.

I'm following the examples set [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/ScriptedMethodsBoundObject.cs) and [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs) (see the constructor).

However, the raise event isn't firing like I figured it should be. It's probably due to my javascript code - or it's possible I've missed something somewhere else.

Here is the js code:

```
private void InjectJsWait(string eventName, string selector, int time, string eventStage)
    {
        string script = @"function waitForElementToDisplay(##SELECTOR##, ##TIME##) {
                                    if(document.querySelector(##SELECTOR##)!=null) {
                                        window.boundEvent.raiseEvent('##EVENTNAME##', {eventStage: ##STAGE##});
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            waitForElementToDisplay(##SELECTOR##, ##TIME##);
                                        }, ##TIME##);
                                    }
                                }";

        script = Regex.Replace(script, "##SELECTOR##", selector);
        script = Regex.Replace(script, "##TIME##", time.ToString());
        script = Regex.Replace(script, "##EVENTNAME##", eventName);
        script = Regex.Replace(script, "##STAGE##", eventStage);

        browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a `MutationObserver`? Also make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: Yeah, I'm injecting the JS after LoadingStateChanged event has fired and passed the !IsLoading test. I've read a lot about MutationObserver but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: I see in the example on mozilla how the script is written, that makes sense to me. 

However, I would still need to bind this script to a boundObject and have an event raised in C# to check if the element is finally there, right? I'll go experiment with this and see if I can get it working with a MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) should be able to do this.

You would simply have to check the observed change and filter out the one you need; no guessing whether or not an event has fired or element has been added.

Keep in mind that this needs Chrome 18+ or 26+ to work

Comment: Yes, I've been wondering if that's the way to go, I'm just clueless about how to implement it. I'm looking deeper into it now.

Comment: So the issue is I still have to fire an event when the element is finally on page in order to pass the data back to C#, through a boundObject class. I'm testing this now. Thanks leuan. :)